# All my Node.js apps crash unpredictably at the same time

Tags: node.js, pm2

I've written two simple Node.js apps, each of which run a server on a port (1337 and 1338), and using PM2 (and Keymetrics) to keep them alive, but every few days all three Node.js apps (including PM2) crash simultaneously. I'm fairly new to Node.js and am not sure how to investigate the source of the problem.

DETAILS:

The two servers respond to incoming GET requests. One is to automatically do a GIT fetch/pull in response to a Bitbucket trigger, and the other converts a URL to PDF and sends the PDF back to the browser (using wkhtmltopdf). They both work fine while they're running.

I'm running Node.js v0.12.4.

When the three apps go down, my first indication is from my Uptime (https://github.com/fzaninotto/uptime) instance on OpenShift which emails me to say one of my Node.js servers is down, returning `"connect ECONNREFUSED"`.

A couple of minutes later Keymetrics emails me saying `"Agent is offline: Keymetrics Agent seems to be offline"`.

In other words, ALL my node.js stuff seems to go down at the same time; neither of the two apps nor even PM2 are running. I thought Node spawned a process for each app, so how could they all go down at once?

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

I've tried digging through the ~/.pm2/pm2.log but haven't been able to find anything useful in there. Maybe I just don't know what to look for.

`$ pm2 resurrect` always brings everything back to life just fine.

Comment: Are you sure pm2 goes down with the node apps? the pm2 is irrelevant to the app it manages, it couldn't shut down with the app, if it shut down, there must be some problem with the environment, not the apps.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The Keymetrics email tells me that the PM2 server monitor is going down but I will double-check this on the server next time the other apps go down. If it's true (i.e. all three node.js apps are going down together) then I think you're right — it must be the environment. I've re-titled the question.

Comment: do you have a local dev environment in which you can test? For fun (but really: to properly debug), run pm2 locally, with your two apps, and then kill pm2, but not your apps. Then see if your apps now crash (for instance, if you forgot to add security checks around pm2 calls, good bet that a missing pm2 instance makes your apps crash)

Comment: what is the host status when they are crashed ? memory/cpu utilization for example, I experienced PM2 crash before

Comment: @sayume I think you're onto something with this line of reasoning. All the node apps (PM2 plus the 2 apps) are definitely stopping, either simultaneously or very close to each other. So, what environmental problem could cause such a thing?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans — I tried what you said, setting up PM2 locally (OS X, like the server), started the two apps, killed PM2, the apps stayed running just fine.

Comment: @AbdullahShahin Re host status, the server is well spec'd (8GB RAM, i7, SSD etc) but sometimes gets hit hard by comment spam attempts. `top` returns the following: 
```Load Avg: 2.67, 2.48, 2.43  CPU usage: 6.18% user, 4.86% sys, 88.95% idle
SharedLibs: 13M resident, 8688K data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 100091 total, 956M resident, 41M private, 371M shared.
PhysMem: 5319M used (1888M wired), 2866M unused.
VM: 1483G vsize, 1063M framework vsize, 115228237(0) swapins, 116459099(0) swapouts.```

Comment: @jeff-h, could you please replace PM2 with forever and see how it goes, my experience with PM2 been tough little bit, I had so many node processes that consumes relatively a good amount of machine specs, on any action on PM2, it suddenly crashes, I replaced it with forever and it works just fine.

Comment: @jeff-h It sounds like the node itself crashes. The job converting to PDF is a cpu-intensive job I am afraid it is not suitable for node to do it, maybe it is the reason the node crashes, there is a possibility that the node itself run out of memory and cpu and cause this crash. You can look into the node log to see if it is happening.

Comment: Did you ever seem to resolve this? I've been having similar issues and can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: @robere2 It's been a while, but sadly I don't believe I ever did resolve it. I rebuilt my PDF converter in PHP, based around [BrowserShot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) (primarily to leverage Google's then-new Puppeteer) and served with nginx on a $5 linode. Its been rock solid ever since. The new setup literally never stops for any reason, ever. I am sure nodejs is capable of that kind of reliability — I just didn't manage it.

Comment: Okay, thank you! For me unfortunately it only happens like once per month so it's hard to debug :( I'll keep trying though!

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to latest PM2 version:

```
$ npm install pm2 -g
$ pm2 update
```

Comment: I've done this, and the problem persists. Currently running 0.14.7.